# Manually choosing colors in ListPlot

Tags: color, plotting

I have a ListPlot of 4 data sets (tables) and I want to manually choose what color each one has.

```
data1 = Table1
data2 = Table2
```

etc.

and then

```
ListPlot[{data1,data2...},PlotRange-> Automatic]
```

This just gives 4 random colors for each data set. Can I somehow choose each color myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the colours with the option `PlotStyle`, for example:

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
         PlotStyle -> {Green, Red, Blue, Yellow}]
```

This makes the first set green, the second one red, the third one blue, and the fourth one yellow.

There are also other things you can change, e.g. the size of the points:

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3, data4}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
        PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, PointSize[0.1]],
                      Directive[Red, PointSize[0.05]],
                      Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.01]],
                      Directive[Yellow, PointSize[0.07]]}]
```

The `Directive` makes both specifications (colour and point size) to apply to the same data set.

Comment: Works, thank you!